# Java Web Start JAVAWS command line arguments

Tags: java, java-web-start

I need to activate webstart by passing command line arguments in my code. I have seen [Passing command line arguments to javaws (Java WebStart) executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396426/passing-command-line-arguments-to-javaws-java-webstart-executable/5074610#5074610) but could not get the solution which can take multiple arguments though we could use -open or -print.

I need to run 'javaws http://appServerURL:port/context/sample.jnlp' with following arguments

1. -u
2. username
3. -p
4. password
5. -s
6. C:/ProgramFiles/saple/some.bat -Ip 10.44.219.109 -Usr readwrite -Pwd readwrite

Your help is much appreciated.....

Comment: Also I'm aware of <arguments> section in a JNLP file but arguments have to be passed during run time....

Comment: It would be great if I can get the usage of -open option in case of multiple arguments being passed.

Answer (score 2):

Create a batch file like

```
set JRE_HOME=c:\Program Files\java\jre1.5.0_12
set ARG=

set ARG=%ARG% -Xbootclasspath/a:"%JRE_HOME%\lib\javaws.jar";"%JRE_HOME%\lib\deploy.jar"
set ARG=%ARG% -classpath "%JRE_HOME%\lib\deploy.jar"
set ARG=%ARG% -Djnlpx.home="%JRE_HOME%\bin"
set ARG=%ARG% -Djnlpx.slashport=1322
set ARG=%ARG% -Djnlpx.jvm="%JRE_HOME%\bin\javaw.exe"
set ARG=%ARG% -Djnlpx.remove=false

rem activate if you want to debug your client
rem set ARG=%ARG% -Djnlpx.vmargs="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8001"

set ARG=%ARG% -Djava.security.policy=file:"%JRE_HOME%\lib\security\javaws.policy"
set ARG=%ARG% -DtrustProxy=true -Xverify:remote -Djnlpx.heapsize=NULL,NULL

set ARG=%ARG% -u username -p password -s C:/ProgramFiles/saple/some.bat -Ip 10.44.219.109 -Usr readwrite -Pwd readwrite

"%JRE_HOME%\bin\javaw.exe" %ARG% com.sun.javaws.Main http://appServerURL:port/context/sample.jnlp
```

Comment: Thanks for the response....but I'm not in a position to run a batch file. I t would have been great if  I could pass dynamically like using -open option in javaws command